# Issue with writeRaster function

Tags: r, function, error-handling, raster, tiff

I have this piece of code:

```
library(rgdal)
writeRaster("~/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/namefile.tif", layer="namefile", driver="GeoTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

And the following error message:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'writeRaster' for signature '"character", "missing"'

Does someone know what's wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to write to a file? `writeRaster` expects a variable name as the first argument:

```
writeRaster(my.raster.object, "~/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/namefile.tif", layer="namefile", driver="GeoTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```